# Mapping Elasticsearch with Python

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, elasticsearch, mapping

I have JSON docs (referred to below as "file_content") that have strings that I want all set to not_analyzed. I am *trying* to accomplish this as such:

```
if not es.indices.exists(index='telemfile'):
                es.indices.create('telemfile')                                                  #  Create the index to work with
                namapping = {
                    "mappings": {
                        "telemetry_file": {
                            "dynamic_templates": [{
                                "string_fields": {
                                    "match": "*",
                                    "match_mapping_type": "string",
                                    "mapping": {
                                        "type": "string",
                                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
                es.indices.put_mapping(index='telemfile', doc_type='telemetry_file', body=namapping)

            es.index(index='telemfile', doc_type='telemetry_file', body=file_content)
```

but I get the following error:
 MapperParsingException[Root type mapping not empty after parsing! Remaining fields:   [mappings : {telemetry_file={dynamic_templates=[{string_fields={mapping={type=string, index=not_analyzed}, match=*, match_mapping_type=string}}]}}]]; 
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the "mappings": object from above, and it works.

Comment: which mapping you removed? I can see there are two mappings. And pls tell me is it necessary to indicate whole the part in the json file when mapping or only we mention only needed variables to be mapped? I have the same problem . I posted my question as "Why does geospatial data not convert from numbers to geo-point with Python client with Elastisearch? " Can you help me this pls?